# How to call function in controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angular-ui-router

If in url parameter id is available then i want to call function.

```
    .controller('repeatCtrl', function($scope,$state,$stateParams) {
        if($stateParams.id != ""){
            //Here i want to call itemDetails function 
            $scope.itemDetails(id);
        };
        $scope.itemDetails = function(id) {
            // function body here!!
            alert(id);
        };
    })
```

Comment: What is the problem with above code? It should work..but if you want it to do in different way..please explain what you want

Comment: This code doesn't work function not call and in output display white screen.. i want to call function itself if condition true.

Comment: your if should be `if($stateParams.id && $stateParams.id != "")`

Comment: Thanks dear my problem solved.... i have call function after it's declaration.

Comment: should I add an answer..to close the issue?

Comment: Finally. Ans is call function after it's declaration and it's works.. Add ans i will close this..

Comment: yes I did it already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You issue is you are calling a function before making declaration of it.

```
.controller('repeatCtrl', function($scope,$state,$stateParams) {
    $scope.itemDetails = function(id) {
        // function body here!!
        alert(id);
    };
    if($stateParams.id && $stateParams.id != ""){
        //Here i want to call itemDetails function 
        $scope.itemDetails(id);
    };
})
```